# How much R-value do you need to insulate a garage ceiling with exposed 2x6 rafters in Zone 4?

Tags: drywall, insulation, roof, garage, roofing

We would like to insulate and drywall the garage ceiling to work on projects in the cold winter and hot summer.  (We'll probably install a [mini-split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_conditioning#Mini-split_and_multi-split_systems) or something similar, too.)  **This question is specifically about the ceiling** (but [see this question about the walls](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/255882/125972)).

[This reference](https://www.energystar.gov/campaign/seal_insulate/identify_problems_you_want_fix/diy_checks_inspections/insulation_r_values) says we need to target R38-R60 in Zone 4 for an attic space...but the garage is not an attic.  In addition, the rafters (pictured below) are 2x6's on 24" centers so R23 is about the most we could get in with batts.

**Question: What is the best practice to insulate (and drywall) the ceiling in situations like this?**

[image: Attic insulation zones]

**Picture of the garage rafters:**

[image: Garage rafters]

Comment: The garage is not living space.  Those those R-value recommendations can be relaxed.  But the greater the R-value of the insulation, the easier it will be to heat and cool.

Comment: How often do you plan on using the garage to work on those projects you mentioned?

Comment: And are you talking about insulating against the roof itself - the rafters (generally not recommended) - or using the horizontal ceiling joists?

Comment: The grarge framing in your picture is barely adequate to hold the roof up, and almost certainly will not hold up drywall and insulation without considerable re-engineering/rebuilding. This is common for lightly-built garages - the collar ties can hold the roof from spreading, but have no spare load capacity, particularly being spaced every other rafter.